# Forcing escaping of printable characters when printing bytes in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, byte

I have a bytes object, for instance

```
test = b'\x83\xf8\x41\x41\x41'
```

I would like to print this object to stdout, but if I do, Python converts the printable characters in the object to ASCII:

```
print(test)
b'\x83\xf8AAA'
```

Is there a way to force Python 3 to print the printable characters (in this instance, three 'A's) as escaped bytes?

That is, so that `print(test)` outputs

```
b'\x83\xf8\x41\x41\x41'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the `repr()` output is not configurable; it is a debug tool.

You could use [`binascii.hexlify()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) to get a hex representation:

```
>>> test = b'\x83\xf8\x41\x41\x41'
>>> from binascii import hexlify
>>> test = b'\x83\xf8\x41\x41\x41'
>>> print(hexlify(test))
b'83f8414141'
```

or you could convert each individual 'byte' value to a hex representation:

```
>>> print("b'{}'".format(''.join('\\x{:02x}'.format(b) for b in test)))
b'\x83\xf8\x41\x41\x41'
```

This produces an alternative representation.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own class for this:

```
class EscapeAll(bytes):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'b\'{}\''.format(''.join('\\x{:02x}'.format(b) for b in self))


# b'\x31\x32\x33'
print(EscapeAll(b'123'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way that's 30x ! faster (134 MiB/s on Intel i7-8700, Python2) than

```
''.join('\\x{:02x}'.format(b) for b in test)
```

It avoids iterating using slow, interpreted Python loops and iterates in optimized code. The optimized binascii also contributes to the speed

```
import binascii

hex=binascii.b2a_hex(test)
# add \x prefix
hex2=bytearray(4*len(b))
hex2[0::4]='\\'*len(b)
hex2[1::4]='x'*len(b)
hex2[2::4]=hex[0::2]
hex2[3::4]=hex[1::2]
```

Comment: Seems to work in Python3 too, except the strings `'\\'` and `'x'` need to be bytes, so `b'\\'` and `b'x'`. Also, if we're being picky about speed, it might be worth putting `len(b)` in a variable :)